# Getting exception while extracting Attachment from Lotus Notes(.nsf) file through C# code

Tags: c#, lotus-domino

Can someone please help me as I am getting below exception while casting the itemA object into Notesitem in foreach loop.

> Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'Domino.NotesItem'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{2913158A-2EED-1069-BF5D-00DD011186B7}' failed due to the  following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)). at WindowsApplication2.Form1.btnSearch_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\WindowsApplication2\WindowsApplication2\Form1.cs:line 319}

I am using **Interop.Domino.dll** with code :

```
        NotesSession session = new NotesSession();
        session.Initialize("XXXXXX");
        try
        {
            NotesDatabase NotesDb = session.GetDatabase("", "C:\LotusFiles\\XYZ.nsf", false);

            if (NotesDb == null)
            {
                //System.Console.WriteLine("Can not connect to server.");
            }
            else
            {
                //System.Console.WriteLine("Connected");
            }

            Domino.NotesDocumentCollection col = NotesDb.AllDocuments;
            for (int i = 0; i < col.Count; ++i)
            {
                Domino.NotesDocument doc = col.GetNthDocument(i);

                if (doc.HasEmbedded)
                {
                    object[] itemsA = (object[])doc.Items;
                    foreach (NotesItem item in itemsA)
                    {
                        if (item.Name.Equals("$FILE"))
                        {
                            object[] values = (object[])item.Values;
                            //doc.GetAttachment(values[0].ToString()).ExtractFile(fileSavePath + values[0].ToString());
                        }
                    }
                }



            }
```

Comment: That's fairly straightforward isn't it? It looks like `doc.Items` is not returning `NoteItem`s. Is that expected, can you find documentation for `NotesDocument.Item`? If that's not it, what's the rest of the error that you've truncated: "failed due to the fo..." ?

Comment: I used to do Notes API programming 20+ years ago.  I'm not familiar with the current C# API, but the reason you're getting that message is because the objects in the `itemsA` array do not implement the `NotesItem` interface.  Frankly, I don't know what type they are.  Place a breakpoint on the `foreach` line and inspect the items in the returned array.

Comment: Actually  Interop.Domino.dll  is com component and i have tried everything like regasm.exe to make it work

Comment: I don't think it's a problem with the COM registration. What's happening is that `itemsA` is a collection of COM `IObject` pointers (or maybe `IDispatch`, I'm not sure) but to cast it to a `NotesItem` in C# terms it needs to get a different interface from the COM object which implements the NotesItem methods. It does that by calling `QueryInterface` on the object, and for some reason, that's failing. Perhaps the answer is in the bit of the error message you've truncated: can you give us the rest of the error message please? The bit after "failed due to the fo...".

Comment: `E_NOINTERFACE`: right, so it's not a random failure, it's that the object you're getting back doesn't think it's a `NotesItem` (or rather doesn't implement the interface with that GUID, which hopefully means INotesItem or similar - you can check in the registry). Unfortunately since what it actually is will be hidden behind a COM Proxy (and not that easy to dig out of the C++ code without debug symbols anyway) it's going to be tricky to work out what it actually is.

Comment: The other option I suppose is that it is a NotesItem but using a significantly different / incompatible version of the interface, which they gave a different GUID. Are your C# Notes library and the installed Notes the same version?

Comment: Have you tried declaring itemsA as NotesItem[] instead of object[]?  (Also, you should not use getNthDocument. It doesn't scale. It gets slower as the number of documents increases. Much better is getFirstDocument and then a while loop with getNextDocument.

Comment: @Rup : how can i check the versioning thing please?

Comment: I was just guessing: that might not be a problem with Notes. But you could see if that interface GUID exists in the registry beneath HKCU\Interfaces; if it does, then it looks like your Notes COM library does have the correct version. Otherwise check the documentation for the .NET wrapper and / or make sure they're from the same era, i.e. you're not using a brand new wrapper against a 10-year-old verison of Notes, or try getting a trial of the recent Notes client to see if that fixes the problem. But ideally you'd work out what the objects you do have are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

got it resolved phewwwwwwww... the Interop.Domino.dll was corrupt in my case, all the people facing this issue please don't download Interop.Domino.dll from the internet rather go to Refrence-->Add Refrence-->COM-->Locate Lotus Domino Objects and Bingo !!!